# Solving second order differential equation $y'' = a^2y+b$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have an equation of the form:

$$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=-a^2y+b$$

Then can we say the general solution is:

$$y=A\sin(ax)+B\cos(ax)+\frac{bx^2}{2}$$

Also I know we can find solution using the fact that $$\frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = y'\frac{dy'}{dy}$$
and we integrate but will this solution be general?

Comment: the solution of the homogeneous equation is $$y_h=C_1e^{ax}+C_2e^{-ax}$$

Comment: You say you have the general solution, but have you checked that it satisfies the DE at all?

Comment: @DavidQuinn Sorry for the error, actually there is a negative sign!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry there is a negative sign before $a^2$, apologies!

Comment: OK but even so, why do you have $\frac{bx^2}{2}$?

Comment: in this case is the solution given by $$\frac{b}{a^2}+c_2 \sin (a x)+c_1 \cos (a x)$$

Comment: @DavidQuinn So that second deravitive becomes $b$ :>

Comment: I see my mistake it doesn't satisfy

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Yes I think you gave correct expression!

Comment: it is correct, set it in the differential equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:  try substituting $z = y - b/a^2$ into your original ODE and see what happens.

Comment: Ok now is this solution general?

Comment: @akhmeteni:  if you can find the general solution for $z(x)$ in your new equation (and you should be able to), then the general solution for $y(x)$ is $z(x) + b/a^2$.  Does that answer your question?